# How to reduce the space between the `li` of tree structure

Tags: html, css

Is there away to reduce the tree by reducing the space between li and putting for example Create Road Network and View Roads Networks at the same level to Road Network?
Here is my code tree https://jsfiddle.net/aba2s/fh49807n/4/

```css
body {
  background: white;
  font: normal normal 13px/1.4 Segoe, "Segoe UI", Calibri, Helmet, FreeSans, Sans-Serif;
}

.tree ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 15em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  position: relative;
  /*relative;*/
}

.tree:before,
.tree ul:before {
  content: "";
  display: lock;
  width: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  background: white;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li {
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1.5em 0 0 2em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tree li:before {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 1em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.5em;
  width: 2em;
}

.tree li:last-child:before {
  background: white;
  bottom: 0;
  height: auto;
  top: 1.5em;
}

.tree>li:before {
  border-top: none !important;
}

.tree li div {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 15em;
  min-width: 15em;
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px #8F949A;
  color: #369;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ul.tree {
  margin-left: 0px;
}

ul.tree:before {
  border-left: none;
}


/*
.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}*/
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="tree">
    <li>
      <div class="sticky">Project</div>
      <ul>
        <!-- Sub category -->
        <li>
          <div class="sticky">Road Network</div>
          <ul>
            <!-- Skill -->
            <li>
              <div><a href="http://google.com">Create Road Network</a></div>
              <li>
                <div>View Roads Networks</div>
              </li>
          </ul>
          </li>

          <li>
            <div class="sticky">Zone set</div>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <div>Create Zone Set</div>
                <li>
                  <div>View Zones Sets</div>
            </ul>
            </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @MaikLowrey, could you please helpe me?

Answer (score 1):

You can decrease the margin in here if I understand correctly

```
.tree ul {
  margin: 0 0 0 1em;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  color: #369;
  position: relative; /*relative;*/
}
```

I changed it from 15em to 1em

Comment: @M Arif Sankaya, lots of thanks. That's not what I want exactly. I would like to reduce the space but keeping Create Road Network and View Roads Networks at the same level to Road Network.

Comment: @aba2s What do you mean by 'same level'? Do you mean 'Create Road Network' and 'View Roads Networks' should be children of 'Project', not child of 'Road Network'?

Comment: @M Arif Sankaya, No, they remain child of `Road Network` but I would like to see them on the top vs bottom as now. Or be in the same horizontal postion as `Road Network`